# SSIS 2014 - column mirroring

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2014

I have a table like below:

Col1 | col2 | col3 |col4 | col5

and now after reading this table i want to split it into two parts:

part 1 will have : col1 | col2 | col3 | col4

part 2 will have : col1 | col2 | col3 | col5

I want all rows from the source table to be present in both parts. Its just i have to split first 3 columns in both sides.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Multicast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/multicast-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) transformation. It duplicates rows among two or more outputs. Then you can drop unnecessary columns and direct data to your destinations.
A [good tutorial](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/multicast-transformation-in-ssis/) on Multicast transformation.